# Better way of passing arguments from JNLP to application

Tags: java, parameter-passing, java-web-start, jnlp

I there a better way of passing arguments from the JNLP to a Java Webstart Application?

Currently the JNLP is looking like this:

```
   <application-desc main-class="MyApplication" >
       <argument>arg1</argument >
       <argument>arg2</argument >
       <argument>arg3</argument >
   </application-desc >
```

And in the Code I can use them in the same order:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    for (String value : args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But is little bad, compared to the possibility of named parameters like for applets (or JavaFX) - relying on the order is error prone. 
Is there really no better way with named arguments/parameter?

Comment: You can set system properties.

Comment: @EJP: hmmm seems that this is only working with a signed and STATIC JNLP. That has again other draw backs - any other (similar) options ?